# How to divide number into 3 parts so that each part is in golden ratio to the other parts?

Tags: algorithm, math

Lets say we have the number 100, how can I divide this into 3 numbers, where each number is a golden ratio to another? This will be helpful for laying out website pages.

Comment: @Treycos What? My question is above. How do I divide a number into three parts, so that each part is in golden ratio to each other.

Comment: Nvm, didn't read the title

Comment: How do you want to arrange stuff ? Why do you want to divide a number into 3 parts ? Don't you want to divide the websites area into golden ratio parts ?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I wan't to have three columns on the website, each with a width that is golden ratio to each other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about arithmetic

Comment: www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: Is arithmetic off-topic if its used for a website? I think not, thats why a tag exist for that, it has to be on-topic something by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have three columns with a given width, i'll propose this:

```
col1 = 1
col2 = col1 * 1.61803398875 //Golden ratio
col3 = col2 * 1.61803398875

ratio = totalWidth / (col1 + col2 + col3) 

col1 *= ratio
col2 *= ratio
col3 *= ratio
```

Comment: Good idea! So simple i'm kicking myself.

Comment: This gives: ratio = totalWidth / 5.236067978